# How would I count the time signature 3/4+3/8

Tags: polyrhythm, wind-band

Right now our band director is conducting at 9/8 and we’ve just been counting the start of every measure but I want to know if there’s a better way to do it.

Comment: What does your band director's conducting of 9/8 time look like? Does it look identical to their conducting of 3/4 time or not?

Comment: Can you edit your question and post an example of the music you are talking about? Is it an ongoing rhythm or just one bar?

Comment: Along with @JohnBelzaguy's comment, how it's counted can depend greatly on the actual rhythm of the music.

Comment: We need more context and info. My answer came from a misdirected angle!

Comment: What's the tempo?  Is the conductor conducting nine beats per measure?  If not in 9, "normal" 9/8 is usually conducted in 3, but this would be confusing if the meter is grouped, as indicated, 2+2+2+3; the better choice there would be a 4 pattern where the fourth beat is 50% longer than the first three.  Which is your conductor doing?

Comment: Welcome! Please use the "edit" button to explain more, because it's not clear right now what you're facing. If possible, please include an image of the music, and tell more about how the director is conducting. If you mean that each measure contains 9 eighth notes of equal length, of which 6 are supposed to be grouped as duples and the last three as triples, then beating 3 large beats, each 3 eighth notes long, is a strange choice. Maybe it's inexperience, or maybe it's because of something happening in other parts. *If* this is the case, there's still a better way than just tracking downbeats

Comment: Voting to close for now as unclear; I'll retract my vote once it becomes answerable.

Comment: [Blue Rondo à la Turk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j9GgmGLPbWU), maybe?

Comment: What's the connection between the band director counting 9/8 and your question about 3/4 + 6/8? And are you asking about how they wave their baton/hand, or how _you_ would count aloud/in your head?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question, for some reason I thought it was`3/4+6/8`, but it is really about `3/4+3/8`. What time signature is in the score, can you show an image of the music?

Comment: I don't think we can usefully address this question until you show us a page of this music.

Answer (score 1):

I misread the question so I'm updating my answer, but I've left my original answer below.

The question title showing `3/4+3/8` had me confused whether *additive meter* or alternating meters were involved.

Normal `9/8` would be counted like...

```
  <     <     <
9 _____ _____ _____
8 | | | | | | | | |
  1 + a 2 + a 3 + a
```

...where the meter is compound and so the beat is subdivided by three and the beaming of notes groups by three visually.

Additive meter will use the same number of eighth notes per measure, but the time signature is written additively to show different groupings and accenting...

```
          <   <   <   <
(2+2+2+3) ___ ___ ___ _____
    8     | | | | | | | | |
          1 + 2 + 3 + 1 + a
```

The same grouping, beaming, and accenting could be achieved with alternating time signatures where two time signatures are given at the beginning and then the measures alternate with appropriate grouping, beaming, and accents...

```
    <   <   <   | <     | <   <   <   | <     |
3 3 ___ ___ ___ | _____ | ___ ___ ___ | _____ |
4 8 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 
    1 + 2 + 3 + | 1 + a | 1 + 2 + 3 + | 1 + a |
```

The rhythms using additive or alternating time signatures should have a noticeable rhythmic effect from plain `9/8`. That effect is sort of like *hemiola* or *syncopation*, with a kind of beat/accent displacement, compared to the regular, even beats of `9/8`.

> How would I count the time signature 3/4+3/8

I'm sort of assuming when you say *time signatures* you are referring to what is notated in a score, and that would seem to be alternating time signatures.

> Right now our band director is conducting at 9/8

That would not be the same as the alternating or additive time signature possibilities.

---

Below vertical lines are meant to be note stems, horizontal lines are note beams, `<` is the beat accent, and `3` is for a triplet figure. The bottom line of each of the five examples is how to count the rhythm aloud with one common scheme of syllables.

```
3 <   <   <
4 |   |   |
  1   2   3

  <   <   <
3 ___ ___ ___
4 | | | | | |
  1 + 2 + 3 +

  <     <
6 _____ _____
8 | | | | | |
  1 + a 2 + a
```

Above the eighth notes have the same duration in `3/4` and `6/8` but the accent of the beat is different, three beats versus two beats respectively.

To make `3/4` equal to `9/8` you could use triplets in `3/4`, as below...

```
  <     <     <
3 __3__ __3__ __3__
4 | | | | | | | | |
  1 + a 2 + a 3 + a

  <     <     <
9 _____ _____ _____
8 | | | | | | | | |
  1 + a 2 + a 3 + a
```

... the eighth notes for triplets in `3/4` or `9/8` will have the same duration. But, if the tempo of all five examples is the same, the eighth notes in the second group of examples will move a bit faster than those in the first group.

Comment: My count is 1 & 2 & 3 &  4 & a... where each symbol gets the same duration; the numbers get the internal accents. (Too close to this answer to be worth a comment. Counting 9/8 is different, it's 3/4 but in triplets, 1& a 2 & a 3 & a; the internal accents fall differently,

Comment: My assumption is: The music wants 9 equal eighth notes, grouped 2 + 2 + 2 + 3, and the conductor, either because they're intimidated or for good musical reasons, says "Well, that's 9 total eighth notes; I'll just beat 9/8," and the player wonders how to map their music to the stick pattern. But we'll need clarification to know whether I'm right.

Comment: @AndyBonner. ah, I see it now! My eyes saw 3/8 but it registered to me as 6/8. I will try to revise my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand why there are deleted answers that are correct and concise, nor why there are close votes on this question. With that out of the way:

---

Yes, there is a better way. Normally this would be conducted in four with a longer fourth beat, like this:

```
down & in & out & up & uh | down & in & out & up & uh |
```

I always count in the same pattern as the conductor/director conducts, so I would count this:

```
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & uh | 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & uh |
```

With that in mind, I suggest counting along with your director, so I would count 9/8 so I don't get lost, unless my part had strong rhythms that contradict 9/8. In that latter case... I'm not sure what I would do. Maybe practice with a metronome set to 9/8 so I can follow the conductor better.

Note that in more recent music, this meter would often be written as 9/8 with a notation above the first appearance of the meter of "(2+2+2+3)". Also 1/8 notes would be beamed to show those subdivisions. For an example, see [the perusal score for Frank Ticheli's "Vesuvius"](https://www.manhattanbeachmusiconline.com/frank_ticheli/vesuvius-virtual-score.html) (starting at m. 47 on page 16).

Comment: It's because the way to conduct, and perform, depends on how the composer wanted the emphases to be placed.  The OP failed to do so much as name the piece in question.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I’d always suggest counting in alignment with the conductor, no matter what the piece is. Otherwise you end up trying to follow something contradictory to how you’re understanding the music.

Comment: I agree; my comment should have specified the conductor or group leader